# Python: Manipulate dataframe in user function

Tags: python, function

I want to manipulate a dataframe in a user written function in python. The manipulating code works fine when I run it outside the function. However, when I put it in the function and run the function it runs without an error but not returns any dataframe. My code looks the following:

```
def reshape(file):
  from IPython import get_ipython
  get_ipython().magic('reset -sf')

  #import packages
  import pandas as pd
  import datetime
  import calendar


  #define file path and import files
  path="X:/TEMP/"
  file_path =path+file
  df = pd.read_excel(file_path, "Sheet1", parse_dates=["Date"])
  #reshape data to panel
  melted = pd.melt(df,id_vars="Date", var_name="id", value_name="Market_Cap")
  melted["id"] = melted["id"].str.replace("id", "")
  melted.id = melted.id.astype(int)
  melted.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

  id_to_string = pd.read_excel(file_path, "Sheet2")
  id_to_string = id_to_string.transpose()

  id_to_string.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
  id_to_string.rename(columns = {0: 'id'}, inplace=True)
  id_to_string.rename(columns = {"index": 'Ticker'}, inplace=True)

  merged = pd.merge(melted, id_to_string, how="left", on="id")
  merged = merged.sort(["Date","Market_Cap"], ascending=[1,0])

  merged["Rank"] = merged.groupby(["Date"])["Market_Cap"].rank(ascending=True)

  df = pd.read_excel(file_path, "hardcopy_return", parse_dates=["Date"])
  df = df.sort("Date", ascending=1)

  old = merged
  merged = pd.merge(old,df,  on=["Date", "id"])
  merged = merged.set_index("Date") 
  return merged
reshape("sample.xlsx")
```

This code runs through but returns nothing. Did I made a mistake in the def command or by calling the function? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should upload the code so we can see what you are doing with that dataframe

Comment: Okay, if it helps. I did. But the code itself runs properly without the function wrapper

Comment: Is the last line `reshape("sample.xlsx")` not indented, or is it just Stackoverflow's formatting? If so, then you should indent it so it will be considered part of the function. Otherwise, the `return` statement is also not included.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the return command in the function. But it changes nothing. The  reshape("sample.xlsx")  command is there to call the function. So the non-ident is intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is run with iPython or a jupyter notebook?
It might have worked before because the kernel remembers some state. Before making something into a seperate function instead of a straight script, I do a `restart kernel & run All`

On the code itself, I would split the different parts of the code, so it becomes easier to test the individual parts

## Imports

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import calendar

from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().magic('reset -sf')
```

## Read 'Sheet1'

get the data from the first worksheet and do the first processing

```
def read_melted(file_path):
    df1 = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheetname='Sheet1', parse_date["Date"])
    melted = pd.melt(df,id_vars="Date", var_name="id", value_name="Market_Cap")
    melted.id = melted.id.astype(int)
    melted.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    return melted
```

## Read 'Sheet2'

```
def read_id_to_spring(file_path):
    df2 = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheetname='Sheet2')
    id_to_string = id2.transpose()
    id_to_string.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
    id_to_string.rename(columns = {0: 'id'}, inplace=True)
    id_to_string.rename(columns = {"index": 'Ticker'}, inplace=True)
    return id_to_string
```

## Read 'hardcopy_return'

```
def read_hardcopy_return(file_path):
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheetname='hardcopy_return', parse_date["Date"])
    return df.sort("Date", ascending=1)
```

## Tying it together

```
def reshape(df1, df2, df_hardcopy_return):
    merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="left", on="id").sort(["Date","Market_Cap"], ascending=[1,0])
    merged["Rank"] = merged.groupby(["Date"])["Market_Cap"].rank(ascending=True)  # what does this line do?
    merged_all = pd.merge(merged,df_hardcopy_return,  on=["Date", "id"]).set_index("Date") 
    return merged_all
```

## Calling everything

```
path="X:/TEMP/"
file_path =path+file

df1 = read_melted(file_path)
df2 = read_id_to_spring(file_path)
df_hardcopy_return = read_hardcopy_return(file_path)
reshape(df1, df2, df_hardcopy_return)
```

The only thing that still strikes me as odd is the line `merged["Rank"] = merged.groupby(["Date"])["Market_Cap"].rank(ascending=True)`

## read_excel `sheetname`

`pandas.read_excel` also has a `sheetname` argument, which you can use to only open the excelfile once. Reading excel files can be slow sometimes, so this might make it faster too